# Can access local endpoint with Postman but not with Axios

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to make a simple GET request with Axios in my Javascript React app.  This request works perfectly fine with Postman but I can't get it working with Axios.

I've tried several different code variations but none work.  Here's the simplest version:

```
  import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
  import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRoles = async () => {
      var authToken;

      Auth.currentSession()
        .then(data => { 
          authToken = data.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

      var config = {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken}
      };

      var bodyParameters = {
        key: "value"
      };

      axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/accounts/roles", bodyParameters, config)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });

    fetchRoles();
  }
```

The error I get each time is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2019 14:12:27] "GET /account_management/roles HTTP/1.1" 401 -
Exception getting user An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the GetUser operation: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'accessToken' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [A-Za-z0-9-_=.]+
```

I don't understand this error because I've checked the Auth Token against this RegEx expression and it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the authToken is still a promise when you reference it, could you try this:

```
  import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
  import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRoles = async () => {

      try {
        let data = await Auth.currentSession();
        const authToken = await data.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
       } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
       }

      var config = {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken}
      };

      var bodyParameters = {
        key: "value"
      };

      axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/accounts/roles", bodyParameters, config)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });

    fetchRoles();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it and I feel dumb.

Being new to Axios, I copied code too literally.  The sample Axios code was for a POST.  I suddenly realized that it made no sense to send a payload, via the `bodyParameters`.  Removing that and the GET worked!

Incidentally, and I hope this helps others in the future, prefixing the Auth Token with "Bearer " is entirely optional.  Both of these work fine:

```
  headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken}
```

and

```
  headers: { Authorization: authToken}
```